# How to create full screen view ( Android 4.0+ )

Tags: android

I tried to create a full screen layout to display a imageview. In the lower end devices (below 4.0) i achieved this, unfortunately when i using the same code in higher end devices the system bar won't be hide. When I used this feature `rootView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);` (rootView - my fragment  view), **the system bar is hidden at the moment of application launch**, once i touch the screen the system bar is enabled. How can i **disable** the system bar appearing on user touch until the current activity getting closed?

Comment: question seems to be confusing

Comment: Maybe by using a `DialogFragment` instead of a `Fragment`.

Comment: you are talking about status bar ?

Comment: @AnhSirkDasarp: Yes offcourse

Comment: I achieved this with a `DialoFragment` on Android 4.0+, if you are interested. But I never tried on oldest versions.

Comment: @YoannHercouet: I changed my extends class from Fragment to DialogFragment and i above same line of code, the result will be same. :(

Comment: I will post what I did in 5 min

Answer (score 0):

I think the trick is just to call the native style from Android allowing you to hide the `ActionBar` by default. Then just select the theme you need to use Holo Light, Holo Dark, etc.).
For example:

```
public class PhotoDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

(...)

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    (...)

    //HERE IS THE TRICK
    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_NoActionBar_Fullscreen);

} 

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View fullImageView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.photo_fragment, null);
    (...)

    return fullImageView;
}

(...)
```

Here is my "photo_fragment" XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen_photo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/your_image" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i added your code line, and also i removed my custom theme in manifest. The view reaming same yar.. :(

Comment: You don't need to remove your custom theme. What is your XML layout? I will add mine in case.